# qtcreator cannot work with opencv

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, qt-creator

> QtCreator version: 3.4.2
>
> Opencv version: 2.4.11, build from source code
>
> Qt version: qt5

My opencv code can work independently, my pure Qt code also can work.

My GUI designed by Qtcreator is working, however some errors about libs are generated after opencv code is joined.

Here is the pro file

```
    QT       += core gui
   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION,4){
CONFIG  += c++11
}else {
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
}

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = BCI
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp 
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h 
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS +=  -lopencv_core
LIBS +=  -lopencv_imgproc    
LIBS +=  -lopencv_highgui
```

---

Error information:

```
*** Error in `xxx': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000611600 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36b0077d9e]
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0x290)[0x36b00845d0]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData7reallocEi+0x1f)[0x3d24f0a3ef]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN9QListData6appendEi+0x6e)[0x3d24f0a4ae]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5[0x3d24fdb474]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(_Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_+0x326)[0x3d24fd7596]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5[0x3d24e7a333]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[0x36afc0ff2a]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[0x36afc1003b]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[0x36afc00d2a]

======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00411000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 13512007                           
00610000-00611000 r--p 00010000 fd:02 13512007                           
00611000-00612000 rw-p 00011000 fd:02 13512007                           
016db000-0171d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  

[heap]
3016600000-30170a0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 536855                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.8.6
30170a0000-30172a0000 ---p 00aa0000 fd:01 536855                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.8.6
30172a0000-30172e3000 r--p 00aa0000 fd:01 536855                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.8.6
30172e3000-30172eb000 rw-p 00ae3000 fd:01 536855                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.8.6
30172eb000-30172ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I guess I know what cause this bug, different version of qt. Qt in the qtcreator is qt4, while the program will automatically to link the qt5.

Comment: What is `xxx`? Show the actual code.

Comment: sorry, it is not important, just a pathname and a filename.

Comment: /home/think/projects/wiener/Qt_project/build-BCI-Cleaner-Desktop-Debug/BCI-Cleaner

Comment: I solved it , but I still do not know what is reason cause it.